# pandas quick way to break dataframe by timeindex

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe with a timeindex. But the timeindex is not consecutive.

df with microsecond resolution timestamp index.

Time                        Bid
2014-03-03 23:30:30.383002  1.37315
2014-03-03 23:30:30.383042  1.37318
2014-03-03 23:30:30.383067  1.37318
2014-03-03 23:30:31.174442  1.37315
2014-03-03 23:30:32.028966  1.37315
2014-03-03 23:30:32.052447  1.37315

I want to check if there is minute without any data, so I did resample

```
tick_count = e.resample('1Min', how=np.size)
```

Time                        Bid
2014-03-04 00:15:00    73
2014-03-04 00:16:00   298
2014-03-04 00:17:00   124
2014-03-04 00:18:00   318
2014-03-04 00:19:00    27
2014-03-04 00:20:00     0
2014-03-04 00:21:00     0
2014-03-04 00:22:00   241
2014-03-04 00:23:00    97
2014-03-04 00:24:00    52
2014-03-04 00:25:00   446
2014-03-04 00:26:00   867

so here I find two minutes with no data, how do I separate the original df into multiple
df and each of them has data every minute. In the case above

this first df will start from 00:15 to 00:19, second one starts from 00:22 to 00:26, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the times are sorted, you could use

```
df['group'] = (df['Time'].diff() > np.timedelta64(60,'s')).cumsum()
```

to add a column to your DataFrame, which will classify the rows according to which group they belong to. The result looks like this:

```
                 Time  Bid  group
0 2014-03-04 00:15:00   73      0
1 2014-03-04 00:16:00  298      0
2 2014-03-04 00:17:00  124      0
3 2014-03-04 00:18:00  318      0
4 2014-03-04 00:19:00   27      0
5 2014-03-04 00:22:00  241      1
6 2014-03-04 00:23:00   97      1
7 2014-03-04 00:24:00   52      1
8 2014-03-04 00:25:00  446      1
9 2014-03-04 00:26:00  867      1
```

This is better than having multiple DataFrames, because you can apply fast numpy/pandas operations to the entire DataFrame whereas, if you had a list of DataFrames you would be forced to use a Python loop to operate on the sub-DataFrames individually (assuming you want to perform the same operation on each sub-DataFrame). Doing so is generally always slower.

Typically, the pandas-way to operate on the sub-DataFrames would be to use [a groupby operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). For example,

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby(['group'])
>>> grouped['Bid'].sum()
group
0         840
1        1703
Name: Bid, dtype: int64
```

to find the sum of the bids in each group.

However, if you really wish to have a list of sub-DataFrames, you could obtain it using

```
subdfs = [subdf for key, subdf in grouped]
```

---

For those wanting to reproduce the result above, I put this in a file called `data`:

```
 Time  Bid
2014-03-04 00:15:00  73
2014-03-04 00:16:00  298
2014-03-04 00:17:00  124
2014-03-04 00:18:00  318
2014-03-04 00:19:00  27
2014-03-04 00:22:00  241
2014-03-04 00:23:00  97
2014-03-04 00:24:00  52
2014-03-04 00:25:00  446
2014-03-04 00:26:00  867
```

and ran

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0])    

print(df.dtypes)                            
# Time    datetime64[ns]  # It is important that Time has dtype datetime64[ns]
# Bid              int64
# dtype: object

df['group'] = (df['Time'].diff() > np.timedelta64(60,'s')).cumsum()
print(df)
```

Comment: excellent. thank you. This is exactly what I want to figure out

Comment: by the way, do you know how to exact time part of datetime64?

Comment: You could use `pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time']).time`. (In other words, convert the column to a `DatetimeIndex`, and then pick off the time using the `time` attribute.)